# Crear cola de tipo stream en rabbitmq con Python

Tags: python, rabbit-mq

Estoy intentando encontrar cómo declarar una cola de tipo stream en rabbitmq con python.
He encontrado cómo hacerlo en java pero no en python.
Pienso que al declararla de la siguiente manera

```
channel.queue_declare(queue='cola', durable=True)
```

y marcar los mensajes como persistentes al publicarlos en el exchange puede funcionar, pero pienso que debe haber otra manera.
En java se hace de la siguiente manera:

```
channel.queueDeclare(
  "my-stream",
  true,         // durable
  false, false, // not exclusive, not auto-delete
  Collections.singletonMap("x-queue-type", "stream")
);
```

indicando que el tipo es stream.

Además, revisando el método no veo que pueda aceptar ese parámetro de configuración:

```
def queue_declare(self,
                      queue,
                      passive=False,
                      durable=False,
                      exclusive=False,
                      auto_delete=False,
                      arguments=None):
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo encontré. Con esta sentencia funciona correctamente:

```
channel.queue_declare(queue='cola',
                                  passive=False,
                                  durable=True,
                                  exclusive=False,
                                  auto_delete=False,
                                  arguments={'x-queue-type':'stream'})
```

La inspección me devuelve "Expected type 'DeclareOk | None', got 'dict[str, str]' instead" pero sigue funcionando.

Comment: Que bien que encontraste la respuesta! Por favor acéptala para que otros usuarios con preguntas similares puedan encontrar la información y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas.

Comment: @HeytalePazguato cuando el mismo autor coloca una respuesta, esta la puede aceptar pasada 48 horas después de haber publicado la pregunta.

Comment: @HeytalePazguato hasta pasadas 48 horas no puedo aceptarla, como nos indica Christian. Mañana podré aceptarla. Mil gracias!